# How to select minimum bandwidth of a controller?

Tags: control-system, motor-controller, pid-controller

As a specific example, I'm trying to control the phase currents of a PMSM motor used in an electric vehicle. I'm using a PI controller to do this.

I am familiar with control theory and have ensured a good gain and phase margin. The current controllers use references determined by torque and speed controllers.

When the gains are high, it is susceptible to noise which is hard to model. I want to lower the bandwidth as much as possible with the controller still able to track the reference reasonably well.

Is there some theory or best practice that I can use to figure out how low the bandwidth can be, without resorting to trial and error (including simulation)?

I have a good idea about the torque and rotation speed required from the motor and I also have a system model. Can I use that information to figure out an appropriate bandwidth?

Do I need to determine the bandwidth of the reference signal itself? How do I go about doing that?

The system model for a PMSM motor can be found [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/pmsm.html;jsessionid=d4cf29d714264cc7bcf3a9ce0d91)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Would you add the system model mentioned in the question ? Please use the [edit] link below the question to add the details. Have you tried extracting the transfer functions at the required operating points ? Are you familiar with control system theory ? Please mention what you mean by *performance* ? Different people may have slightly different idea about *performance*. (minimum) Bandwidth requirement is defined by the application. Please provide those details if possible.

Comment: Before attempting to close the loop of your system, what you absolutely need is the *control-to-output* transfer function. What I mean by that is you want to know how a stimulus applied to the control input (a voltage, a current...) travels through the system or *the plant* to form the response (a torque, a speed etc.) and become the variable to control. Once you have it in the form a Bode plot for instance (or an equation), then you can think of a control strategy where crossover frequency and margins come into play.

Comment: I am not very good with control theory. How dynamic is your system? As an example, a fan or centrifugal pump (or blower) is usually not dynamic at all. The torque and speed are nearly constant. But in a positioning application (e.g., CNC machine) the speed and torque are very dynamic. I have nothing quantitative for you but qualitatively, it is obvious that a highly dynamic system will require much more rapid variation of torque and/or speed.

Comment: This is for electric vehicle application, so the torque and speed are quite dynamic. I was hoping to know how those dynamics determine the minimum bandwidth of the phase current controllers.